# Trouble with Authentication on Root Route using Express-OpenID-Connect Middleware with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I'm using the express-openid-connect middleware for authentication in my Express.js application, but I'm running into an issue where authentication isn't working as expected on the root route (/).

Here's the code I'm using to configure my Express application:

javascript
Copy code

```js
// 1. Imports and Initialization
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { auth, requiresAuth } = require('express-openid-connect');
const { sendEmails } = require('./server/api');
const { processContacts } = require('./server/utils');
const { uploadToDb } = require('./server/uploadToDb');
const { addContact, deleteContact } = require('./server/dataToDb');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const apiRouter = express.Router();
const appRouter = express.Router();
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const port = 3000;

// 2. Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const API_KEY = 'my-api-key';
const apiKeyMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const reqKey = req.get('x-api-key');
  if (reqKey && reqKey === API_KEY) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({error: "Invalid or missing API key"});
  }
};

const auth0Config = {
  authRequired: false,
  auth0Logout: true,
  secret: 'secret',
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  clientID: 'client-id',
  issuerBaseURL: 'inner-issuer-base-url'
};

app.use(auth(auth0Config));

// 3. Routes
// API Routes
apiRouter.post('/addContact', apiKeyMiddleware, addContact);
apiRouter.delete('/deleteContact/:contactId', apiKeyMiddleware, deleteContact);

// App Routes
appRouter.post("/contacts", requiresAuth(), async (req, res) => {
  const { templateId } = req.body;
  try {
    const emailGroups = await processContacts(99);
    for (let group of emailGroups) {
      await sendEmails(group, templateId);
    }
    res.json(emailGroups);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred while fetching contacts" });
  }
});

appRouter.post('/upload', requiresAuth(), upload.single('contacts-upload'), (req, res) => {
  uploadToDb(req.file.path);
  res.send('File uploaded successfully');
});

appRouter.get('/', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is the home page");
});

// Use the routers in your main app
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use('/', appRouter);

// Catch all other routes
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Received a ${req.method} request on ${req.originalUrl}`);
  console.log(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out');
  next();
});

// 4. Server Listen
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

In my setup, I'm using two routers: appRouter for routes related to my app's functionality, and apiRouter for my API. I'm applying the requiresAuth() middleware to some routes in appRouter to require authentication.

The problem is that the requiresAuth() middleware does not seem to be triggering authentication on the root route (/). When I navigate to this route, I'm not being redirected to the login page as expected. However, it works fine for other routes in appRouter.

I have confirmed that my Auth0 settings are correct, and I am not seeing any error messages. The authRequired option is set to false when I initialize the Auth0 middleware, as I only want to require authentication on specific routes.

I tried to debug the issue by logging incoming requests, and I also tried enabling the debug option for express-openid-connect, but so far, I have not been able to find a solution.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue, and how I can get the requiresAuth() middleware to properly trigger authentication on the root route?